# write proof that it is possible to obtain the product rule from chain, sum rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

How do I write a proof that it is possible to obtain the product rule from chain rule, sum rule and from $\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x$

Thank you

Comment: Hint: $(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2$

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint $(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$ was enough for the OP, great. Decided to make the hint into an "answer" for the sake of pointing out that it was an interesting question, at least to me.

Interesting because the same trick is a standard thing in an inner-product space, deducing things about the inner product from things about the norm. Never realized it also had application to calculus...

Details added on request: Say $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. Then $$4(fg)'=((f+g)^2-(f-g)^2)'=2(f+g)(f+g)'-2(f-g)(f-g)'=4f'g+4fg'.$$

Comment: Can you explain your point? I don't see how the product rule can be obtained using $(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2$.

Comment: @MrReality Added details to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the details! BTW, how did you know how to solve the problem (because the conditions specified in the problem seemed quite arbitrary to me)? Or is this a normal problem one encounters in calculus?

Comment: @MrReality As I said somewhere above, I"d never seen this. I knew how to do it because it reminded me of a standard thing in inner-product spaces: The "polarization" identity that writes the inner product in terms of the norm. In a real inner-product space, $4<x,y> = ||x+y||^2 - ||x-y||^2$.