# How do I write a proof that it is possible to obtain the product rule from chain rule, sum rule and from $\frac{d}{dx} x^2=2x$?

Tags: derivatives, summation, chain-rule

How do I write a proof that it is possible to obtain the product rule from chain rule, sum rule and from $\frac{d}{dx} x^2=2x$ ?

**Hint**: $(x+y)^2−(x−y)^2$ , but I do not really understand this hint, can someone else give me better hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write proof that it is possible to obtain the product rule from chain, sum rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480390/write-proof-that-it-is-possible-to-obtain-the-product-rule-from-chain-sum-rule)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate as the hint was not enough for this OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow that's a nice question!

Expand
$$
(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2 = ?
$$
Compute the derivative of the left side using chain rule and $\frac d{dx}x^2=2x$, and simplify. You will arrive at the product rule!

Comment: Omg :(, I feel so bad for not getting the hint before, thank you very much :D